# How to place two texts in the middle, but so that the location depends on their length

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I need to limit the position of the `TextView`, depending on how much space it takes up (example in the screenshot below)

[image]

As you can see, in the left example, the `Title` is quite short, so both `TextView` are located in the middle.

In the case like the example on the right, the `Title` takes up a lot of space and goes up, but the `Description` goes down, but both `TextView` still remain in the middle. How can I do this using `ConstraintLayout`?

P.S.: Do not pay attention to the fact that I did not accurately draw examples, I used Paint :)

Comment: What if the title is too long and exceeds the screen height; where do you expect the description would be?

Comment: @Zain In general, I did not think about it, but it can be added ellipsis for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to chain both `TextViews` as "packed" to make both in the middle of the height. This would be applied to the top TV.

This also requires to constraints both `TextViews` to one another, the top TV to the screen top end, and the bottom TV to the screen bottom end.

As the top TV would be lengthy, you'd constraint its height using `layout_constrainedHeight` attribute so that you guarantee it won't go beyond the top screen end, or not to be greedy on the bottom TV.

Here it's assumed that the bottom TV text is short or it would be greedy on the top TV otherwise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_text"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```